# Adding items to an inventory

Tags: python, inventory

I am trying to build a simple text based game for class and need to add items into an inventory. It is supposed to read the dictionary of rooms to find the item then add that item to the players inventory if typed get Item. It should output in this way when in the first room:

```
You are in Entrance Hall
Inventory [Items]
You Don't see anything useful
What do you wish to do?
```

I cant seem to figure out how to get my code to do so. I am probably referencing something wrong but I am very new to coding so I cant see where I am going wrong with this. My code is below, any help is very appreciated.

```
# A dictionary for the simplified text game that links a room to other rooms.
rooms = {
        'Entrance Hall': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Gallery', 'West': 'Library'},
        'Library': {'East': 'Entrance Hall', 'item': 'Book'},
        'Gallery': {'West': 'Entrance Hall', 'item': 'Sword'},
        'Great Hall': {'South': 'Entrance Hall', 'East': 'Dining Room', 'West': 'Cellar', 'item': 'Armor'},
        'Dining Room': {'North': 'Kitchen', 'West': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'Plates'},
        'Kitchen': {'South': 'Dining Room', 'item': 'Knife'},
        'Cellar': {'North': 'Catacombs', 'East': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'Ale'},
        'Catacombs': {'South': 'Cellar'}
    }

instructions = 'A Necromancer has moved into your catacombs to raise an army of the undead! ' \
               'You need to defeat him before he turns the dead against you and the town! ' \
               'Before you can fight him,you are going to need 5 items to aid you. ' \
               'You will need armor to protect your body against his attacks, ' \
               'a book to learn how to protect yourself from his spells,' \
               ' a sword to defeat him, a candle to see in the dark,' \
               'and a bottle of Ale to gather your courage and take on this task. ' \
               'To move type: go North, go East, go West, go South' \
               'to get items type get Item, ex: get Sword\n '

directions = ['go North', 'go South', 'go East', 'go West']
pick_up_items = ['get Ale', 'get Book', 'get Armor', 'get Sword', 'Necromancer', 'get Knife', 'get Candle']

print(instructions)
current_room = 'Entrance Hall'
item_in_room = 'None'
inventory = []

while True:
    if inventory == ['Ale', 'Book', 'Armor', 'Sword', 'Candle']:
        print('Congratulations! You collected all the items, you use you wits to head into the'
              'cellar and defeat the Necromancer!')
    elif current_room == 'Catacombs':
        print('A bolt of magic streaks towards you and your vision goes black..... Game Over!')
        break
    # displays the players current location
    print('You are in the {}.'.format(current_room))
    print('Inventory:', inventory)
    if item_in_room:  #checks to see if there is an item in the room
        print('You see a'.format(item_in_room))
    else:
        print("You don't see anything useful")

    # gets the users input
    command = input('\nWhat do you wish to do? ')  # this controls the movement
    if command in directions:
        command = command.split()[1]
        if command in rooms[current_room].keys():
            current_room = rooms[current_room][command]
        else:
            # if the player inputs a bad movement
            print('You cant go that way!')
    # Checks to see if the player types a 'get' command and adds the item in the room to the players inventory.
    if command in pick_up_items:
        command = command.split()[1]
        if command in rooms[current_room].keys():
            inventory = current_room['item']
        else:
            # if the player inputs a item not in the room
            print('You cant get that item here!')
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I am understanding your question right, that you want to add items to a list named inventory.

In your code here:

```
if command in rooms[current_room].keys():
        inventory = current_room['item']
```

You are setting inventory equal to the item but I think what you wish to accomplish is adding an item to the list. So you should do this:

```
inventory.append(current_room['item'])
```

This will add/append a the item to the list.

I hope this is what you were looking for.
And please don't post your full code in future, only post the required parts
And also please be more implicit with your query.

Have a wonderful day.

Comment: Yeah im still new here to stack overflow so I didnt know what code to include.
The only other issue i am having is that it doesnt seem to read what items are in each room. How would i fix that?

Comment: Your `item_in_room` variable is never changed anywhere in your program, So, the if else condition is always evaluating false.

Comment: If this answer helped you please click upvote on the answer as it would help me out alot as well. :)

Comment: so how would i go about updating it?

Comment: You should have a dictionary with all the items in a room and when ever the user changes their room and have the var item_in_room equal to the dictionary.

Comment: And please also click the tick under the answer to mark it as correct if you are satisfied with your original query. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would I add it around where the user moves rooms then?  Like here:   

     if command in rooms[current_room].keys():
        current_room = rooms[current_room][command]
        item_in_room = rooms[current_room]

Comment: You would need a list of items in the room instead of a dictionary, like this:
`'Entrance Hall': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Gallery', 'West': 'Library', "items": ["item1", "item2", ....] }`

Comment: And then you would do:
`if command in rooms[current_room].keys(): current_room = rooms[current_room][command] item_in_room = rooms[current_room]["items"]`

Comment: Hopefully this is the last question i have to ask from you but when i try to get the item in the room it only gives me my error code instead of adding it to the inventory. Is there something I need to add?